# Full width-of-screen background slider using CSS on a static website

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a static website and I need to create a background slider with a fixed height of 587px. The width of each image is 2000px wide, but the user only needs to see the image to the width of his or her screen beyond 1000px, the width of the website. The image does not ever need to move, stretch, or respond in any way.

It needs to look and function like, www.adsphoenix.com/2013design/index5.php, but be a background slider. If you select "view background image" (Firefox), you will see the image is wider than most screens. It is aligned to the center and top.

The problem I have is finding a slider to allow the image to go outside of the 1000px website. For example, www.adsphoenix.com/2013design/. All of these images are 587 x 2000px.

Something similar to this would be, www.chattanoogafun.com. However, this slider stretches.

Do you know of a pre-built slider that would work? Or a slider I could change the alignment of? Or something I could do to my code to allow it to work? I have hosting with Blue Host.

Comment: ECMAScript is *not* Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the image as background image of a slider div with CSS and use this code:

```
.slider_div { //or another selector

    background: url(../path/to/image) center center no-repeat;

}
```

If you want to slide your background, you'll need inline CSS to set the background of the slider divs (or use jQuery for that).